# How to keep date format based on its category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Stats `has_many` Results.

When a user goes to edit a stat the result's date format switches to `[Month][Day][Year]` even if the category was a monthly `averaged`, which means the date format should have remained `[Month][Year]`.

**stat.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('.date-format-switcher').click(function(event){
    event;
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'stat_categories_instance') {
      $('.day').show();
     } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'stat_categories_averaged') {
        $('.day').hide();
    }
})
  $('.add-form-padding').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
    if($('#stat_categories_instance').is(':checked')) {
      $('.day').show();
    } else {
        $('.day').hide();
    }
})
});
```

In the **_form** the user chooses a category & can add results:

```
<% Stat::CATEGORIES.each do |c| %>&nbsp;
  <span class="label label-primary">
  <%= label(c, c) %>:</span>
  <%= f.radio_button(:categories, c, :class => "date-format-switcher") %>
<% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :results do |result| %>
  <%= render 'result_fields', :f => result %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to_add_association f, :results do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Result
<% end %>
```

To further clarify the issue, when the user goes to edit the _form, the **_result_fields** `date_select` resets as an `instance` category (`[Month][Day][Year]`) even if it was submitted as an `averaged` category (`[Month][Year]`).

```
<%= f.text_field :result_value, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Result' %>
<%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :with_css_classes => true, :class => "date-select" %>
```

I think the problem is with the javascript, but if you need further code or clarification please let me know :]

**stat.rb**

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :results
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
    scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
    scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
    validates :categories, :metric, :results, presence: true

    CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
end
```

### BY REQUEST

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Personal Control Center</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-160f5c0baab5966f165d1ceda4baf96f.css" />
  <script src="/assets/application-3553266740dedab0ebae9bc455264add.js"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="0L0etiyhQeSadH9jJycPZun8eOh0WzPg2iy1djmdQOUJzyEwX+tVBKktlu5AhHd0Zyw6vlZUMzOosRcYAbvFbA==" />
  <meta name="description" content="Habits | Goals | Values | Stats" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  <!-- Tells app to be mobile responsive -->
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Cd6S_eRTPmKoMPGhVcYjfFTeYsptlUiSQvdDajy1vmI" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Personal Control Center</a>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="/habits/new">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <b>Habit</b>
        </a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="/valuations/new">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <b>Value</b>
        </a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="/goals/new">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <b>Goal</b>
</a>    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/stats/new">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <b>Stat</b>
</a>    </li>


    <li><a href="/activities">Feed</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Account 
      <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users/1/edit">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <p class="text-center">
       <div class="jumbtron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><b>Edit Stat</b></h1>
     <p>If there is no struggle,<br>
      there is no progress. Positive anything <br>
      is better than negative nothing.
     </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- this variable should be assigned in your controller action-->
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <script src="/assets/stat-7dc4e947c11e58375e6b13b6d489f73b.js"></script>

<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_stat" id="edit_stat_1" action="/stats/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="pu54sleLSOjc4xlsXm1d8jdOATUAxkYTLA+f4AIp6iR/nEc0JMFcCO+68OE5ziXguZ5DYyLJRsBekj2OOg9vrQ==" />
  

<div class="add-form-padding">
<form>
  
      <div class="form-group">
        &nbsp;
          <span class="label label-primary">
          <label for="Averaged_Averaged">Averaged</label>:</span>
          <input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="Averaged" checked="checked" name="stat[categories]" id="stat_categories_averaged" />
&nbsp;
          <span class="label label-primary">
          <label for="Instance_Instance">Instance</label>:</span>
          <input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="Instance" name="stat[categories]" id="stat_categories_instance" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="five" placeholder="Enter Action" type="text" value="Ran" name="stat[action]" />

        <input class="form-control" id="five" placeholder="Enter Metric" type="text" value="miles" name="stat[metric]" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="tags" placeholder="Enter Tag(s)" value="run" type="text" name="stat[tag_list]" />
      </div>

    <div id="results">
      
      <div class="nested-fields">
<div class="nested">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Result" type="text" value="45" name="stat[results_attributes][0][result_value]" id="stat_results_attributes_0_result_value" />
    <div class="center">
        <select id="stat_results_attributes_0_date_value_2i" name="stat[results_attributes][0][date_value(2i)]" class="month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6" selected="selected">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="stat_results_attributes_0_date_value_3i" name="stat[results_attributes][0][date_value(3i)]" class="day">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select id="stat_results_attributes_0_date_value_1i" name="stat[results_attributes][0][date_value(1i)]" class="year">
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>

      <div class="bad-pad">
        <span class="label label-danger">Bad:</span>
        <input name="stat[results_attributes][0][bad]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="stat[results_attributes][0][bad]" id="stat_results_attributes_0_bad" />
      </div>
      <div class="bad-pad">
        <span class="label label-danger">
            <input type="hidden" name="stat[results_attributes][0][_destroy]" id="stat_results_attributes_0__destroy" value="false" /><a class="remove_fields existing" href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
</a>        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="stat[results_attributes][0][id]" id="stat_results_attributes_0_id" />
      <div class="nested-fields">
<div class="nested">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Result" type="text" value="27" name="stat[results_attributes][1][result_value]" id="stat_results_attributes_1_result_value" />
    <div class="center">
        <select id="stat_results_attributes_1_date_value_2i" name="stat[results_attributes][1][date_value(2i)]" class="month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="stat_results_attributes_1_date_value_3i" name="stat[results_attributes][1][date_value(3i)]" class="day">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select id="stat_results_attributes_1_date_value_1i" name="stat[results_attributes][1][date_value(1i)]" class="year">
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>

      <div class="bad-pad">
        <span class="label label-danger">Bad:</span>
        <input name="stat[results_attributes][1][bad]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="stat[results_attributes][1][bad]" id="stat_results_attributes_1_bad" />
      </div>
      <div class="bad-pad">
        <span class="label label-danger">
            <input type="hidden" name="stat[results_attributes][1][_destroy]" id="stat_results_attributes_1__destroy" value="false" /><a class="remove_fields existing" href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
</a>        </span>
```

Comment: Can you show me the html of your edit form(Just select the form, right-click and click 'view selected source')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues that I notice:

- (minor) You're binding to the click event of the radio button, rather than the change event. Be aware that this won't work for someone using a keyboard to fill out the form.
- Whenever the radio button changes, you're showing/hiding *all* of the day fields on the page.
- Reusing values for your `id` attributes. Those are supposed to be unique on the page. I don't think this is your issue, but it can cause weird bugs. Switch to `class`.

Here's what I would recommend.

- Wrap each "stat" on the form in a div with a class that indicates if it's averaged or instance. i.e. `<div class="stat averaged">`.
- Modify your .erb to output the right class names on the div (so it's correct when the page first loads).
- Modify your javascript to change the class name of the parent div (`$(this).closest('.stat').removeClass('averaged').addClass('instance');`)
- Setup css rules to hide the day field for averaged stats (`.stat.averaged .day { display: none; }`)

Comment: Thanks James for your help! I'm trying to integrate your writing into code, but it's causing all sorts of issues. I want to hide all the day fields when the category is `averaged`. What do you mean wrap each "stat" on the form? The _form itself is for stats. How would I integrate this line `($(this).closest('.stat').removeClass('averaged').addClass('instance');)`? Sorry for all the questions I just can't get it to work and it maybe my fault not yours. Can you show your recommendations with my code so I can see where I've been going wrong James?

Comment: Your question has too many parts for me to post a simple working solution. I'd suggest replicating the problem in a "clean" environment. Make a view with hardcoded radio buttons and a single date field. Add the minimum amount of javascript necessary. You'll probably figure it out on your own during that process. If not, replace the code in this question with your clean example and you'll get better answers.